# EF marking entities as modified with no changes

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Using proxies in EF6.1.3 with the following code (VB.NET): -

```
Dim DB As New BMContext

Dim sl = DB.StockLevels.First
Dim ee = (From e In DB.ChangeTracker.Entries Where e.Entity Is sl).Single
sl.Level = sl.Level
```

Checking ee.State before the final line correctly gives a state of Unmodified.  After that line it shows as Modified even though the property has been set to what it already was.  This even triggers an UPDATE when I call SaveChanges!

Data class code: -

```
Public Class StockLevel
    Public Overridable Property ID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Level As Integer?
End Class
```

Obviously my actual code is rather a lot more complex as this example is pretty pointless other than demonstrating the problem.

Comment: As this post suggest you may end up adding a lot of code. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37304/update-only-modified-fields-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

> "change-tracking proxies mark a property as modified whenever any value is written to it."

From [source](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/)

Basically, since you're assigning a value to this property (even though it is the exact same value), you are receiving a `Modified` state.

Comment: That just seems really rubbish to me.  Shouldn't it at least double-check before performing the UPDATE?

Comment: You may find [this](http://codepaq.blogspot.com/2014/09/entity-framework-update-only-changed.html) interesting. I know it is C#, but you can see what is going on fairly clearly.  There is also a decent article on [msdn blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/09/self-tracking-entities-original-values-and-update-customization.aspx) regarding this. I'm not sure what to tell you aside from different ways to implement or override the change tracking configuration. You can also use `AsNoTracking` from the `DbQuery<T>` class.

Comment: That's a slightly different problem - in that situation all the fields are being updated instead of some.  I'm dealing with a situation where in many cases none should be updated.  I have posted code to fix it in an answer myself, but it seems ridiculous that this is necessary - Linq to SQL handles this far better.  AsNoTracking doesn't help me in this case because when I initially retrieve the data all of the results are mixed together and I don't even know which ones have changed until I have processed them.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 I can see why you would say the reference are addressing a different problem, when in reality they are not. They are checking if the object has mutated by comparing properties of the previous state to the current state, which is another approach to solving your problem. If my answer isn't helpful let me know and I can delete it

Comment: C - leave it - it may be useful to someone else.  I don't know if GetDatabaseValues runs a query though, but that would defeat the purpose in my case as that would add even more queries.   CurrentValues seems to do the job though and it doesn't run a query.  I've upvoted the answer for giving a reference to explain the behaviour since it explains that there isn't anything that can be directly done about it and a workaround is definitely needed.  I had been hoping that there was some config option I had missed or something but the fact that EF just behaves this way isn't your fault!

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up writing this to call before SaveChanges, although I find it a bit ridiculous that I need to...

```
Public Class DbEntityModification

    Public ReadOnly Property FieldName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property OriginalValue As Object
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentValue As Object

    Public Sub New(FieldName As String, OriginalValue As Object, CurrentValue As Object)
        _FieldName = FieldName
        _OriginalValue = OriginalValue
        _CurrentValue = CurrentValue
    End Sub

End Class

<Extension()> Public Function GetChangedValues(e As DbEntityEntry) As IDictionary(Of String, DbEntityModification)

    Dim ret As New Dictionary(Of String, DbEntityModification)

    For Each propname In e.CurrentValues.PropertyNames
        Dim nv = e.CurrentValues.Item(propname)
        Dim ov = e.OriginalValues.Item(propname)

        Dim Changed = False
        If ov Is Nothing Then
            Changed = nv IsNot Nothing
        ElseIf Not ov.Equals(nv) Then
            Changed = True
        End If

        If Changed Then
            Dim m As New DbEntityModification(propname, ov, nv)
            ret.Add(propname, m)
        End If

    Next
    Return ret
End Function

<Extension()> Public Sub MarkUnchangedAnyUnchangedEntities(ees As IEnumerable(Of DbEntityEntry))
    For Each ee In ees
        If ee.State = EntityState.Modified Then
            If GetChangedValues(ee).Keys.Count = 0 Then
                ee.State = EntityState.Unchanged
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
<Extension()> Public Sub MarkUnchangedAnyUnchangedEntities(context As DbContext)
    context.ChangeTracker.Entries.MarkUnchangedAnyUnchangedEntities()
End Sub
```